# Ternary expression in string in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error, python-3.6, ternary-operator

How do I make this ternary expression evaluated without raising any error? When I run this without string and `eval()`, it works perfectly until when I try running it with string and `eval()`.

```
c = {1: "y += 1 if y == 1 else print('F')",
    2: "y -= 1 if y == 2 else print('F')",
    3: "x += 1 if x == 1 else print('F')",
    4: "x -= 1 if x == 2 else print('F')"}

for i in range(1,5):
    eval(c[i])
```

Error Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.../mazefinder.py", line 25, in <module>
    eval(c[i])
  File "<string>", line 1
    y += 1 if y == 1 else print('F')
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I want this code to increment or decrement the x or y!

Comment: What are trying to achieve?  There are almost certainly better ways.  See about XY [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing "statement" to the "eval" function that expects expression. Assigning a value to a var is a "statement". So, it won't raise an error if you provide expression, but not statement.

Let's consider you really need to use exactly "eval", then you can do the following:

```
x = 1
x += eval("1 if x == 1 else 0") # a statement is outside of an expression
x += eval("-1 if x == 2 else 0")
y += eval("1 if y == 1 else 0")
y += eval("-1 if y == 2 else 0")
```

We change the value instead of operator, so we are able to move the statement out of "eval" having it the same for both condition results.

But, even not considering the "SyntaxError" error, you would get "TypeError" error in your own example in case of "False" result for conditions, because "print" function returns "None".

Then, you have here much more problems and antipatterns such as:

- "iterating" by indexes is not needed in your example at all.
- "dict" is wrong object type to use here, because your example needs only values not paying attention to keys.
- You do redundant actions such as separating one condition to several separate ones.
- Completely unclear the need to use "eval", which should be done only if you really need it.